# Replace special character with keyboard shortcut live on input

Tags: windows, keyboard

Is there any way to replace a special character with a keyboard shortcut live?

For instance: Writing `$` would actually press `ctrl+n` or `arrow key left`

Every help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`This is primarily speculation with a little experience and research mixed in.`

This sort of thing is easy enough if you are checking in an application that currently has focus, but creating a universal keypress hook? Not so much.

I built a C#/C++ program in grad school that intercepted keystrokes intended for another application, but I was only able to do it by waiting for the desired application window to open, auto-opening my own pop-up window to receive the input, and then passing keystrokes back to the original window.

I'm not saying it can't be done, period, but my background knowledge (though slightly dated) and a little cursory research isn't turning up anything in the basic scripting world that would satisfy what you appear to be after.

The only way I know how to do it (which is likely wrong) would be to have hooks in every open application, and when a textbox on the application gained focus give focus to your own text-receiving app. Analyze the keypresses, and then pass the desired text/keypresses on to the original app/textbox. This would require prior knowledge of the "windows" (i.e. all objects) in all possible apps on the machine you're working on, so you would know when a textbox received focus. 
If I recall, it might be possible to tell when keys are being pressed (if you have hooks in all apps) and re-direct from there, but you might lose the first keystroke, even then.

Again, this is primarily speculative.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Since the window or even the cell (not excel though) will be in focus, the problem lies only in catching that input and changing it accordingly.

Comment: @Blufftl, unless you built the app you are observing or it offers custom shortcuts, I think you would be stuck with the same situation I had: create an app that enumerates the open windows, watching for a particular one; when a "cell" (a window within that window) is given focus, give the focus back to your app instead and filter keystrokes (some keystrokes might immediately return focus, others are shortcuts for special characters or button clicks, etc); when the mouse is clicked or a particular key/sequence is received, return focus (and/or mouseclick) to the app. Spy++ may be a help for you